# PigLatin fails to read file from hdfs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am trying Pig demo codes following its online manuscript.

Firstly I create a test file named `myfile.txt`. It contains six integers in two rows:

```
4 5 3 
1 2 3
```

The file is put into hdfs using `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal myfile.txt /user/myfile.txt`

Then I run

```
A = LOAD '/user/myfile.text';
DUMP A;
```

But obtain the following error message:

```
2014-10-08 14:15:54,259 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2014-10-08 14:15:54,594 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2014-10-08 14:15:54,692 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2014-10-08 14:15:54,693 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2014-10-08 14:15:54,909 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2014-10-08 14:15:54,998 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2014-10-08 14:15:55,006 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Using reducer estimator: org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.InputSizeReducerEstimator
2014-10-08 14:15:55,013 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.InputSizeReducerEstimator - BytesPerReducer=1000000000 maxReducers=999 totalInputFileSize=12
2014-10-08 14:15:55,015 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting Parallelism to 1
2014-10-08 14:15:55,016 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - creating jar file Job7804857093829884774.jar
2014-10-08 14:15:58,229 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - jar file Job7804857093829884774.jar created
2014-10-08 14:15:58,266 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2014-10-08 14:15:58,304 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2014-10-08 14:15:58,353 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient - Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
2014-10-08 14:15:58,806 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2014-10-08 14:15:58,964 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2014-10-08 14:15:58,968 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.https.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.https-address
2014-10-08 14:15:58,969 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum
2014-10-08 14:15:59,024 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2014-10-08 14:15:59,025 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2014-10-08 14:15:59,051 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 1
2014-10-08 14:16:00,533 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_201410081312_0015
2014-10-08 14:16:00,534 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases A
2014-10-08 14:16:00,534 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: A[2,4] C:  R: 
2014-10-08 14:16:05,098 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2014-10-08 14:16:05,098 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_201410081312_0015 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2014-10-08 14:16:05,099 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2014-10-08 14:16:05,109 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2014-10-08 14:16:05,111 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.0.0-cdh4.7.0  0.11.0-cdh4.7.0 hdfs    2014-10-08 14:15:54 2014-10-08 14:16:05 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_201410081312_0015   A   MAP_ONLY    Message: Job failed!    

**Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/user/myfile.txt"**
```

It seems that Pig doesn't connect to hdfs, and thus fails to access the file. Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you check hadoop logs? Do you see your hadoop job on JobDetails page at http://<yourhadoopJobTrackerMasterNode>:50030/ ?

Comment: Can you findthe file via hdfs dfs -ls?

Comment: I am facing the same issue.. did you find the root cause of the issue ?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, any solutions? Permissions are correct

Answer (score 0):

Change the settings on the file.
Perhaps you are not able to read the file.

In the Linux environment change the permissions of the file using

```
chmod 755 myfile.txt
```

After that do the CopyFromLocal command.